# Juniper optimize using Ipopt and Cbc for MINLP with constraints including maximum and minimum ERROR: LoadError: AssertionError: length(x) == d.len

Tags: julia, nonlinear-optimization

I have used Juniper for solving MINLP problem imitating a facility location problem for data centers allocation using Ipopt and Cbc and registering a function for evaluating the maximum as follows

```
f(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10) = maximum(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10)

optimizer = Juniper.Optimizer nl_solver= optimizer_with_attributes(Ipopt.Optimizer, "print_level" => 0) mip_solver = optimizer_with_attributes(Cbc.Optimizer, "logLevel" => 0) model = Model(optimizer_with_attributes(optimizer, "nl_solver"=>nl_solver, "mip_solver"=>mip_solver, "registered_functions" => [
                Juniper.register(:f, 10, f; autodiff=true)
            ]))

JuMP.register(model,:f, 10, f; autodiff=true)
```

The decision variable here is the allocation[i,j] which is a binary matrix indicating whether a *j* customer branch will be associated with *i* datawarehouse. Our constraints are about:

1. limiting that a customer is served by one data center
2. we will only build 3 data centers
3. we have minimum latency requirements for customer branches which are related to the distance

After running the optimization we get the following error when running the `optimize!` method :

`ERROR: LoadError: AssertionError: length(x) == d.len Stacktrace: [1] eval_objective(::JuMP._UserFunctionEvaluator, ::SubArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}},true}) at C:\Users\oswel\.julia\packages\JuMP\qhoVb\src\nlp.jl:1168 [2] eval_and_check_return_type(::Function, ::Type{T} where T, ::JuMP._UserFunctionEvaluator, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at C:\Users\oswel\.julia\packages\JuMP\qhoVb\src\_Derivatives\forward.jl:5 [3] forward_eval(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{JuMP._Derivatives.NodeData,1}, ::SparseArrays.SparseMatrixCSC{Bool,Int64}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::JuMP._Derivatives.UserOperatorRegistry) at C:\Users\oswel\.julia\packages\JuMP\qhoVb\src\_Derivatives\forward.jl:163 [4] _forward_eval_all(::NLPEvaluator, ::Array{Float64,1}) at C:\Users\oswel\.julia\packages\JuMP\qhoVb\src\nlp.jl:503 [5] macro expansion at C:\Users\oswel\.julia\packages\JuMP\qhoVb\src\nlp.jl:571 [inlined] [6] macro expansion at .\timing.jl:233 [inlined] [7] eval_constraint(::NLPEvaluator, ::SubArray{Float64,1,Array{Float64,1},Tuple{UnitRange{Int64}},true}, ::Array{Float64,1}) at C:\Users\oswel\.julia\packages\JuMP\qhoVb\src\nlp.jl:569 [8] eval_constraint(::Ipopt.Optimizer, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}) at C:\Users\oswel\.julia\packages\Ipopt\P1XLY\src\MOI_wrapper.jl:1113 [9] (::Ipopt.var"#eval_g_cb#48"{Ipopt.Optimizer})(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}) at C:\Users\oswel\.julia\packages\Ipopt\P1XLY\src\MOI_wrapper.jl:1305 [10] eval_g_wrapper(::Int32, ::Ptr{Float64}, ::Int32, ::Int32, ::Ptr{Float64}, ::Ptr{Nothing}) at C:\Users\oswel\.julia\packages\Ipopt\P1XLY\src\Ipopt.jl:202 [11] solveProblem(::IpoptProblem) at C:\Users\oswel\.julia\packages\Ipopt\P1XLY\src\Ipopt.jl:513 [12] optimize!(::Ipopt.Optimizer) at C:\Users\oswel\.julia\packages\Ipopt\P1XLY\src\MOI_wrapper.jl:1441`

We don't know why does this happen or how to solve it.

Our code is shown here:

```
f(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10) = maximum(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10)

optimizer = Juniper.Optimizer
nl_solver= optimizer_with_attributes(Ipopt.Optimizer, "print_level" => 0)
mip_solver = optimizer_with_attributes(Cbc.Optimizer, "logLevel" => 0)
model = Model(optimizer_with_attributes(optimizer, "nl_solver"=>nl_solver, "mip_solver"=>mip_solver, "registered_functions" => [
                Juniper.register(:f, 10, f; autodiff=true)
            ]))

JuMP.register(model,:f, 10, f; autodiff=true)


###################################
# variables

dist_to_branches = rand(1:400, (5,10))
Latency_branches = rand(1:80, (1,10))                                           # branches latency requirements                     (10x1)
distance_to_latency = 0.1


@variable(model, allocation[1:5,1:10], Bin )    # allocation of each branch to a certain datacenter

################################
# Constraints

# maximum each data center serves 6 locations
for i in 1:5
    @constraint(model, sum(allocation[i,j] for j in 1:10) <= 6)
end

# each branch is served by only one data center
for j in 1:10
    @constraint(model, sum(allocation[i,j] for i in 1:5) == 1)
end

# only 3 datacenters can be built

@NLconstraint(model, sum( f( allocation[i,1] , allocation[i,2] , allocation[i,3] , allocation[i,4] , allocation[i,5] , allocation[i,6] , allocation[i,8] , allocation[i,9] , allocation[i,10]) for i in 1:5) == 3 )


# constraint for latency
for j in 1:10
    @constraint(model, distance_to_latency * sum(allocation[i,j] * dist_to_branches[i,j] for i in 1:5) <=  Latency_branches[j])
end

######################
# objective


@objective(model, Min, sum( sum(allocation[i,j] * dist_to_branches[i,j] for i in 1:5) for j in 1:10))
optimize!(model)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `maximum` in an optimization model you need to introduce a proxy variable and make the model linear.

Suppose that you have:

```
m=Model(Cbc.Optimizer)
@variable(m, 4 <= x <= 10)
@variable(m, 3 <= y <= 12)
```

You do not write now:

```
@objective(m, Min, max(x,y))
```

Rather than that you introduce a proxy variable:

```
@variable(m, z)
@constraint(m, z >= x)
@constraint(m, z >= y)
@objective(m, Min, z)
```

In this way you end up with a linear model (and, in your case, you do not even need Juniper)

Comment: Thank @PrzemyslawSzufel for your response, our problem here is that the constraint involves the **summation** of several maximum values, not just one maximum. Because of that, we couldn't find a turnaround by splitting the max() into multiple constraints, as the constraint is about the summation of these multiple max() results. That's why we couldn't do it in a linear way.

Comment: I am pretty sure you should be able linearize that but perhaps this becomes non Julia question. `min` is non differentiable and as far as I know quite does not work in JuMP models - however I could be wring here.

Comment: and here is how: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/711/how-to-formulate-linearize-a-maximum-function-in-a-constraint/712#712    Hope that helps